# List difference (omit one list from other list) in NetLogo

Tags: list, netlogo

In case we want to omit one list from other list in Netlogo , how we should write the code?
For example, first list is [1 2 3 4 5]
And second list is [4 5]
In this case what code should be written to remove list 2 from list 1 so as to having a new list comprises of 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Your description is vague. Can you be more precise about the expected behavior? What if the second list were `[5 4]`, would those items still be removed, or not? What if the second list were `[3 4]`? And so on.

Comment: I want to remove common elements of a list from another one. eg: list 1: 1 2 3 6 . list2: 1 2 3 4 5. result  should be: 4 5

Comment: If we're removing the second list from the first, don't you mean the answer should be `[6]`?

Answer (score 3):

Code:

```
to-report difference [l1 l2]
  report filter [not member? ? l2] l1
end
```

Sample runs:

```
observer> show difference [1 2 3 4 5] [4 5]
observer: [1 2 3]
observer> show difference [1 2 3 6] [1 2 3 4 5]
observer: [6]
```