# Removing repeated elements from lists in Netlogo

Tags: list, netlogo, removeall

Hello i'm having trouble creating lists in Netlogo. Suppose that i have 2 lists:

```
 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]
 [3  5  7   9  12]
```

So i want to create a new list without the repeated elements of the 2 list, so I can get the list:

```
[1 2 4 6 8 10 11]
```

I tried the command remove but it only remove 1 item at time and also the filter command but i think that i don't applied it very well. I aslo tried to mix the 2 list and use the remove-dulicates commands but also doesn´t worh here. Any suggestions?

Comment: check Seth Tisue answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895592/list-difference-omit-one-list-from-other-list-in-netlogo I tried with your example and it works!